# Some problem with json symbol in my project. How to recognize them to the original look

Tags: json, symbols

i have some symbols in a json file, I can recognize their original look? Here is a picture:
[image: part of file of my json file]

What i need to do to check original symbol? I really need your help because i have zero knowledge about json